# Need help can not install SublimeClang on my ubutun 12.0.4 PC

Tags: python, clang

I encounter a problem when i install the Sublime Clang on my ubutun 12.0.4 system.
I follow the instructions on the:
https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang
but when i enter the step:

```
pythonbrew install --configure="--enable-unicode=ucs4" 2.6
```

It reported an error:

```
ERROR: Failed to install Python-2.6. See /home/chen/.pythonbrew/log/build.log to see why.
The error detail is:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./setup.py", line 1904, in <module>
        main()
      File "./setup.py", line 1899, in main
        'Lib/smtpd.py']
      File "/home/chen/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.6/Lib/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/home/chen/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.6/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/home/chen/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.6/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/chen/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.6/Lib/distutils/command/build.py", line 134, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/home/chen/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.6/Lib/distutils/cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/home/chen/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.6/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/chen/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.6/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 343, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "./setup.py", line 104, in build_extensions
        missing = self.detect_modules()
      File "./setup.py", line 962, in detect_modules
        sqlite_libdir = [os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sqlite_libfile))]
      File "/home/chen/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.6/Lib/posixpath.py", line 119, in dirname
        i = p.rfind('/') + 1
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

my python verison is
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug 1 2012, 05:14:39)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2

is not 2.6 as required.
I don't know what is happened and how could solve this problem. could any one give me some help on this ? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem, this is a python install issue, you can skip this error by rename the sqlite3.h under /user/include/ folder